# How does this code for Kruskal's MST algorithm work?

Tags: c++, algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm

Below is the C++ code for *Kruskal's algorithm* for finding the minimum cost spanning tree of a graph given by my instructor.

I did not understand the code well. I want to know exactly what part of the code is checking for formation of a cycle in the growing forest of included edges.

I also want to know that what exactly is the purpose of the `parent[]` array.

Also, is it a better way than checking for cycles using *DFS* (depth first search)?

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int i, j, k, a, b, u, v, n, ne = 1;
int min, mincost = 0, cost[9][9], parent[9];

int find(int);
int uni(int, int);

int main()
{
    printf("\n\tImplementation of Kruskal's algorithm\n");
    printf("\nEnter the no. of vertices:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nEnter the cost adjacency matrix:\n");

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&cost[i][j]);
            if(cost[i][j] == 0)
                cost[i][j] = 999;
        }
    }

    printf("The edges of Minimum Cost Spanning Tree are\n");

    while(ne < n)
    {
        for(i = 1, min = 999; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            {
                if(cost[i][j] < min)
                {
                    min = cost[i][j];
                    a = u = i;
                    b = v = j;
                }
            }
        }
        u = find(u);
        v = find(v);
        if(uni(u,v))
        {
            printf("%d edge (%d, %d) =%d\n", ne++, a, b, min);
            mincost += min;
        }
        cost[a][b] = 999;
    }
    printf("\n\tMinimum cost = %d\n",mincost);
}

int find(int i)
{
    while(parent[i])
    i = parent[i];
    return i;
}

int uni(int i,int j)
{
    if(i!=j)
    {
        parent[j]=i;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note:

I am aware that the code is messed up a bit and user input will result in failure in case the user enters a value more than `9`, but I don't want to focus on that part without understanding how it works. I just know that it selects the minimum cost edge, checks it for the formation of the cycle and then sets its value to infinity (here `999`). I don't know how and where it is checking for cycle formation. Please help by explaining.

Comment: Everyone here has limited time. You will hardly find somebody to explain your code for you if it isn't very short and well presented. What in the world is `int i,j,k,a,b,u,v,n,ne=1;`? How are we supposed to explain what each of those mean?

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, there is no "C/C++" language. You must decide whether you are using C or C++, and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I know there is no such lang. and I don't think that there exists such a popular belief. All I wanted to say that the above code works with both, a C compiler and a C++ compiler. It's not the code I am worried about, it's the logic it uses for checking presence of cycles.

Comment: Sorry, I admit the code is messed up and I forgot to provide any comments, anyways, i j and k are your usual loop variables (just realized that k is unused). a, b, u, v are variables used to store the location of the row and column in the loop. n is the total number of edges and ne is the number of edges visited. Another reason for not including comments is that I myself have not understood the purpose of all variables like for example the parent[] array.

Comment: @50calrevolver, those of us who frequent SO know well that many who pose questions here indeed seem not to recognize that C and C++ are distinct languages, neither a subset of the other.  If indeed it is important to you to write in the common subset of the two -- not a trivial task -- then do say so.  Otherwise, chose **one**.

Comment: I absolutely didn't mean to offend any of you language experts and I agree that since I intended to try it on a C++ compiler, I should mark it as C++ code. Also, yes I should have changed printf and scanf to cout and cin respectively.

Comment: @50calrevolver -- Why don't you simply single step through the code with a debugger?  Then you will see what variable values are at each step, how the program flows, etc.

Comment: I know that the code is error free and works perfectly. I also know that when which variables are passed as arguments and what changes happen to them. I am just not able to infer any logical algorithm looking at the code. Where does it check for presence of cycles and by what exact means is what I want to know.

Comment: @50calrevolver *I know that the code is error free and works perfectly* -- The purpose of the debugger is for you to see the program flow, not to see if the program works perfectly.  Seriously, any programmer who is not familiar with how a program works, but knows what it should be doing, steps through the code with a debugger.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant. I have used an IDE debugger several times and have also understood how control flows throughout each line of code. Yet after that I am unable to understand the logic or the algorithm used for the particular problem of Kruskal's. Maybe because I am stupid, but I am simply not able to figure out why is this working.

Comment: I will not hold it against anyone who has trouble understanding a program with stuff like `int i,j,k,a,b,u,v,n,ne=1;` in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code inside the `while` loop in `main` finds the lightest edge that has not yet been considered. That edge is between nodes `u` and `v`. The edge can form a cycle **only if `u` and `v` already belong to the same tree.**

This:

```
u=find(u);
v=find(v);
```

finds the roots of the trees to which `u` and `v` belong. Then `main` passes those two roots to `uni`:

```
if(uni(u,v))
  ...

int uni(int i,int j)
  {
    if(i!=j)
      {
        parent[j]=i;
        return 1;
      }
    return 0;
  }
```

If the two roots are the same, the code does nothing, the edge is not used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also what exactly does the uni(u, v) function do?

Comment: @50calrevolver: If the roots are the same, it does nothing and returns 0; if the roots are different, it unites the two trees by making one root the parent of the other, and returns 1. If it returns 1, the calling code reports that the MST contains the edge, and updates the cost of the tree.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know exactly what part of the code is checking for formation of a cycle in the growing forest of included edges. I also want to know that what exactly is the purpose of the parent[] array.

You seem to understand the general idea of Kruskal's algorithm, but not some of the more important details.  In particular, I have to assume that you do not understand the central and essential use of a ["disjoint set"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) (a.k.a. "set union" and other names) data structure in this algorithm.  For if you did, you would surely recognize that in your code, that is the role served by the `parent` array.  Even if you didn't guess from the name, the `find()` and `uni()` functions are a dead giveaway.

The code uses the disjoint set structure to track which groups of vertices are connected by the edges so far added to the graph.  The `find()` function determines which set a given vertex belongs to, and candidate edges are rejected if the two vertices belong to the same set.  The `uni()` function combines two sets into one when two subgraphs are joined by accepting an edge.

> Also, is it a better way than checking for cycles using DFS (depth first search)?

Performance details depend somewhat on the implementation of disjoint set. The one here is particularly simple, but more sophisticated ones can reduce the amortized cost of searches, for a better performance bound on the algorithm overall than can be achieved by using DFS instead.

Comment: I admit that I had no prior knowledge of any such data structure and hence I was not able to figure out or even guess its usage and thus the logic of the code. Thanks for the helpful explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Alright. Before proceeding to the explanation feel free to take a second and read [this](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/minimum-spanning-tree/tutorial/) wonderfully written tutorial on Kruskal's Algorithm over on HackerEarth so that you have a general idea of what to look for.

Now as for the algorithm:

Note: First of all ignore the first three lines, just look at the code in main and assume that all variables are declared before hand.

Now let's begin:

```
printf("\n\tImplementation of Kruskal's algorithm\n");
printf("\nEnter the no. of vertices:");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("\nEnter the cost adjacency matrix:\n");
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&cost[i][j]);
        if(cost[i][j]==0)
            cost[i][j]=999;
    }
}
```

Those first lines ask for the number of vertices and an adjacency matrix with the cost of each vertex to any other vertex. It also looks like that when there isn't any edge connecting 2 vertices the cost is set to 999 so that it doesn't bug the code when set at 0.

Here is what an adjacency matrix looks like.

Assume that your graph looks like this[image: Simple weighted directed graph]
The adjacency matrix would be the following:

```
   1  2  3
  _________
1| 0  0  11
2| 0  0  0
3| 11 6  0
```

Meaning that 1 is connected to 3 with cost 11. 2 isn't connected with any vertex and 3 is connected to 1 with cost 11 and to 2 with cost 6. The code above would change the above matrix to:

```
   1    2    3
  _____________
1| 999  999  11
2| 999  999  999
3| 11   6    999
```

So that the algorithm doesn't pick 0 as minimum cost. And avoids selecting non-connected vertices.

After that we have:

```
printf("The edges of Minimum Cost Spanning Tree are\n");
while(ne < n)
{
    for(i=1,min=999;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j <= n;j++)
        {
            if(cost[i][j] < min)
            {
                min=cost[i][j];
                a=u=i;
                b=v=j;
            }
        }
    }
    u=find(u);
    v=find(v);
    if(uni(u,v))
    {
        printf("%d edge (%d,%d) =%d\n",ne++,a,b,min);
        mincost +=min;
    }
    cost[a][b]=999;
}
printf("\n\tMinimum cost = %d\n",mincost);
```

Firstly you have to know that Kruskal's algorithm uses Connected Components to figure out whether 2 vertices are connected or not(this is also the reason why kruskal's algorithm doesn't create circles). So let's what the code does.

```
for(i=1,min=999;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j <= n;j++)
    {
        if(cost[i][j] < min)
        {
            min=cost[i][j];
            a=u=i;
            b=v=j;
        }
    }
}
```

This is somewhat straight forward. What it does is goes through the matrix and finds the smallest value in it. So for the example I gave it would first find 6.
So min=6, u=3(the starting vertex), v=2(the ending vertex). So now in order to understand what will follow you will have to READ about disjoint sets and connected components. Luckily for you there is a 10 min read tutorial again over at HackerEarth which will help you understand how Connected Components work. You can find it [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/disjoint-data-strutures/basics-of-disjoint-data-structures/tutorial/).

So here is what's happening. The algorithm says the smallest cost right now is from 3->2 that costs 6. let's add this to the graph that we are building at the background with connected components and set the cost to 999 so we don't reconsider it. So here: `u=find(u);`

It goes to the parent array and checks at position 3(`arr[3]`) who is the parent? The answer is 3 since we haven't connected it to any other component yet. Next it does the same thing for 2(`arr[2]`) which also stays the same since we haven't connected it. To anything else. And then unifies them to one. That is the array now becomes:

```
[1, 2, 3] -> [1, 3, 3] (minCost is now equal to 6)
```

Then it adds min to minCost which is the answer. And changes the cost from 3->2 to 999 so we don't reconsider it.

It repeats that process so that we have:

```
    // min=6, u=3, v=2
    [1, 2, 3] -> [1, 3, 3] // minCost = 6
    // min=11, u=1, v=3
    [1, 3, 3] -> [1, 3, 1] // minCost = 17
    // min=11, u=3, v=1 !!! CAREFUL NOW
    Moving over to 
    parent of parent[3] == parent[1] meaning that they have the same parent so they are CONNECTED. 
    if(uni(u,v)) <-- This won't run since uni(3, 1) will return 0 meaning that they are connected so the min won't be added to minCost this time.
```

And this is where the algorithm ends. It prints a final cost of 17 and you are done. The ne variable is just there as a counter to make prints easier to understand.

I hope this helps you. Be sure to read the tutorials I linked they will really help you understand the logic because the Wonderful Kruskal's Algorithm.

The links mentioned above:

Kruskal's algorithm: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/minimum-spanning-tree/tutorial/

Connected Components: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/disjoint-data-strutures/basics-of-disjoint-data-structures/tutorial/